# How can I use my IntelliJ 'custom' keyboard shortcut in WebStorm?

Tags: intellij-idea, keyboard-shortcuts, webstorm

I am using a lot of custom shortcuts in IntelliJ.
I would like to use custom shortcuts like this in PyCharm and WebStorm.

I tried `File > Manage IDE Settings > Export Settings` but it doesn't work.

Is there another way?

Comment: Are you sure the keymap was exported with your settings? You can copy the keymap XML file manually between IDE Configuration directories: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#config-directory,

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thank you for your help. I tried a few more times and eventually succeeded.